# Iterate through RadDataGrid Winrt

Tags: datagrid, telerik, windows-runtime

I'm using the RadDataGrid controls for Windows 8 and I want to be able to loop through the items in the datagrid. Can it be done

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You will find that the community is much more eager to help when you share your work.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried everything. I know there is no form of Datagrid for Winrt as its more consumer focused, so i used Datagrid controls from Telerik but i cant seem to find how to iterate between the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say what you're having problems with without any details in your question.

`RadDataGrid` is an `ItemsControl` meaning that it has `ItemsSource` property to which you bind the collection of items you want the control to show. This collection implements `IEnumerable` allowing you to iterate through it.

Declaration in XAML:

```
<telerik:RadDataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"/>
```

Iterating the items collection in code:

```
foreach (var item in (MyDataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable))
{
    // process item as required
}
```

Since you know the items and the collection you're using, you can cast it to a more specific type. You can even hold a typed reference to the data bound object to avoid the need for casting.